# hash utility for locations of utilities on Windows: does a $ hash -d or $ hash -r equivalent exist for windows?

Tags: windows, pip

Trying to fix an issue with pip on Windows:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5221#issuecomment-381568428

One suggested solution is to use the **hash utility (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hash.1p.html)

Does such a utility exist for Windows?

```
hash -d pip
'hash" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `where`?

```
Prompt>where pip
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe
```